# Better way to add a parameter with null value to sqldatasource control

Tags: c#, sql

I add parameters to Sqldatasource control dynamically from code behind.

```
sq1.UpdateParameters.Clear();
sq1.UpdateCommand = "sp_upn";
sq1.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

is there a better way to add null parameter ?better than code below?(set value to null just when adding, not later)

```
sq1.UpdateParameters.Add("imgid","");
sq1.UpdateParameters["imgid"].DefaultValue = null;
```

UPDATED
**The parameter is not always NULL.It may have Int value based on condition.( if user uploaded an image)**

I am using Sqldatasource Control and not a sqlcommand and I can not use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("imgid", DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Does specifying `DbType` help?

Comment: @tia Thank you .yes!  sq1.UpdateParameters.Add("imgid", DbType .Int32,null); worked. please add it as answer.I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `DbType` when adding parameter. For example:

```
sq1.UpdateParameters.Add("imgid", DbType.Int32, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Would suggest adding that default value in your procedure itself and don't pass anything while calling from client code like

```
create procedure sp_upn
@imgid varchar(30) = null,
//other declarations
```

Comment: It is not always null. It may be null or may have an int value